# Play Framework and java problems

Tags: java, playframework

I've started the tutorial "Play for java. I've downloaded activator, unzip it and create a new java-project.

Loaded it with IntellliJ IDEA 14.1.3, set java 8 to the project SDK and language level, then run the application. Everything works fine exept a few strange  moments.

1. Start page with documentation and "Play for Java" tutorial describe the index method as:

   public static Result index() {
       return ok( index.render("Your new application is ready."));
   }

Fine, but template contains not static method. If I define it as static, than I'll get such error:
"Compilation error" -> value index is not a member of controllers.Application 
And the error line is in routes file:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
```

So, what is wrong? According to tutorial and documentation it should works with static methods...

2. I'm also getting annoying error in my IDE: "Cannot resolve method ok(java.lang.Object)" for the method above.
3. If I'm leaving index method non-static, than my IDE highlight method index() in the routes config file with mart "Cannot resolve: under constraction". This error dissapear for static method, but in this case the project won't compile successfully.

Can someone give an explanation?